# undefined reference error when trying to build gprc

Tags: cmake, grpc

I tried to build grcp with CMake on Linux, but running into some errors.
Log report

> /usr/bin/ld: libgrpc++_test_config.so.1.31.0:undefined reference to 'google::ParseCommandLineFlags(int*, char***, bool)'

I've already installed gflags and gflags-devel package and I tried

```
ldd libgrpc++_test_config.so.1.31.0
```

but there is no link to gflags...

I think the cmake/gflags.cmake has some error in line 28 because `find_package` target is gflags but the next line `TARGET` become gflags:: gflags...

This is my build command:

```
cmake ../.. -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_GFLAGS_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON

make

make install
```

Comment: Have you run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to initialize the third_party modules your local clone of your grpc/grpc repo?

Comment: no,but i download the submodule code and unzipped it into the third_party/${package} folder.finally i modify the `gflags::gflags` to `gflags` and make success